# How to do a javascript redirect and include post data

Tags: php, javascript, post, redirect

I am designing an web application. This application has a number of users.

All users can see and use a search form - however only those who are logged in can submit the form properly.

So when the form is submitted - BEFORE redirecting to the results page and showing the results, a jquery ajax function fires, checks if the user is logged in and if the user is logged in does a
`window.location.replace('searchresults.php')` to the search results page.

How can I ensure that the correct POST data (from the form input fields) is included in the redirect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create hidden form and submit it via javascript instead of `window.location.replace('searchresults.php')`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a window.location redirect and supply POST data. The HTTP spec just does not support the redirect header with any POST data.

I think your searchresults.php page should always load - but if they are not logged in, don't perform the search. Far simpler.

Comment: The whole point is that individuals are not taken from the page. Page reloads should not occur at this point in the app.

Comment: ok, still not a problem. Use ajaxForm http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ and load that into your DOM